# Procesar input dinamicos con PHP

Tags: php, html, sql, backend

Que tal? espero puedan ayudarme.

Estoy utilizando un formulario dinámico para crear estudios de laboratorios clínicos. Tengo el siguiente formulario que con `JavaScript` me permite generar estos mismos `input` de forma infinita según quiera el usuario:

```
<form id="additems" method="POST" action="../php/upload.php" data-content="false" data-process="false">
    <input id="item1" class="form-control form-item" type="text" name="item[]" placeholder="Nombre de item" required>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="medida[]" placeholder="Medida">
    <select id="tipoInput1" class="custom-select tipoInput form-item" name="tipo_input[]" id="tipoInput" required>
        <option value="">Tipo input</option>
        <option value="1">Normal</option>
        <option value="2">Amplio</option>
        <option value="3">Seleccionable</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Como se puede apreciar, mis `input` los voy a recibir como arreglo en `PHP`. Mi problema es que no se como hacerlo.

Había utilizado el ciclo `for` para recibir un solo valor en el `PHP` y procesarlo, pero no se como recibir múltiples valores como el ítem, la medida y el tipo de `input`.

Lo que deseo es procesar las variables en `PHP` que llegan como arreglos e introducirlos en la base de datos.

Comment: Agrega tu código PHP con el que tratas de recibir y procesar dichos inputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En `php` recibirás cada `array` de `inputs` por separado. Si siempre tienes el mismo numero de valores en cada `input` (es decir todos los parámetros son obligatorios) entonces cada `array` de `inputs` será del mismo tamaño. Luego puedes usar un solo índice para recorrer todos los valores, por ejemplo:

```
$_POST['item'][0];
$_POST['medida'][0];
$_POST['tipo_input'][0];
```

Serán el primer grupo de `inputs` (y cambiando el 0 irás a otras posiciones). Entonces podrías usar el mismo ciclo `for` que ya usas pero para recorrer cada `array`:

```
$count = count($_POST['item']);
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
    $item = $_POST['item'][$i];
    $medida = $_POST['medida'][$i];
    $tipo_input = $_POST['tipo_input'][$i];
    
    // y haces lo que necesitas hacer para cada grupo de inputs.
}
```

Se puede de otras formas pero creo que vale para efectos didácticos.

Comment: Muy clara y sencilla la explicación.